# Check if field type is same as generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I want to determine if a field is typed as the subclass of a generic type.

For e.g

```
Foo extends Bar<Foo>

Foo x;
```

How do I tell if the field x is typed as a subtype of `Bar<Foo>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Type genericSuperclass = x.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
if (genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    Type[] types = 
       ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass).getActualTypeArguments();
}
```

Then you can use `Class.isAssignableFrom`, if `type instanceof Class`, to verify whether it is `Foo` or not.

i.e.

```
if (types[0] instanceof Class) {
    if (x.getClass().isAssignebleFrom(((Class) type[0]))){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ParameterizedType`? You can't use generic type parameters (the typical `K`, `V`, `E`, `T`) in `instanceof`, can't you?

Comment: `ParameterizedType` represents (in this case) the following information: `Bar<Foo>` - i.e. (as far as I understood) - what geejay needs to know.

Comment: Thanks but how do I use this to determine if it is a subtype (of Bar that is)?

Comment: @Bozho: wouldn't this be analogous to doing `aList instanceof List<String>`? Which you can't do in Java?

Comment: No, java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType is something that can be retrieved by reflection from the superclass of a class, and it contains the actual type information for that superclass.

Comment: @ColinD, @Bozho: Fascinating stuff. This is the first time I've seen `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

Comment: @geejay - as I said, using `isAssignableFrom`. see my update.

Comment: I think I have a better solution. Simply Bar.class.isAssignableFrom(x.getClass())

Comment: well, of course, in case you know the class beforehand. I thought you want something dynamic.

Comment: That'll tell you if you have an instance of `Bar` (you could also do `x instanceof Bar` if that's all you want) but not whether that `Bar`'s type argument is `Foo`.

Comment: Sorry peoples. I think I confused everyone here, nonetheless the solution given is still handy. Thanks all.