# Get Type of a generic Field in Java Class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
class A<Type>{

    private Type id;

}

class B extends A<String>{


}

B b = new B();
Field idField = //reflection code to get id field
```

How from "idField" , we can get the exact type of idField , means String instead of Type ?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? I can't see any possible use for this. In the example given, it is obvious that the type is String because the class is defined that way, and won't be changing.

Comment: I don't see how this is an exact duplicate of the other question. In this specific case, the type is available at runtime.

Comment: The real duplicate is here: [Check if field type is same as generic type in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2758582/697449)

Comment: @digitalFresh I want to know the field type at runtime in order to set a value (String , int or whatever)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yes the type is available at runtime. but how to get it?

Comment: @kycdev Need a couple more reopens before an answer can be added... (Although I'm pretty sure whatever you are planning is a bad idea. If a plan involves reflection, it usually is.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. 
But I'm guessing that you would like to determine the concrete type of field 'id'.

```
    public class A<T>{
    public T id;
    public Class<T> idType;

    public A(){
        idType = (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}

public class B extends A<String>{

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.idType);
}
```

The last sysout statement in the above code snippet will print 'java.lang.String'.

This is a technique that is very commonly used when writing generic functionality in the base class.